# Sum named range consists of several columns and rows

Tags: excel

I have a list that is divided into countries vertical and years horizontal like below.

I need to sum all numbers for 2020 respective for each country. Each country have several lines divided into different months.

```
             2020                     2021
         J | F | M | A | M |...| J | F | M | A | M |...
-------------------------------------------------------
Denmark |  |   | 15|   | 12|   |   |   |   |   |   |
Norway  |  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 10|   |   |
Germany |  |   |   | 11|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
```

Each year have been called a named range, e.g. `Year2020`.
I have tried using `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Year2020;CountryRNG;Country))`, `MATCH/INDEX` and also `=SUM(INDEX(Year2020;0;MATCH(1E+99;INDEX(Year2020;1;0))))`.

How can I do this with one formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Country=CountryRNG)*Year2020)
```

With a few notes:

- CountryRNG and Year2020 have the same number of rows
- Year2020 is only the data.  No Text or Errors in the data field
- Both ranges are limited to the data and does not include full column references.  This is to limit the number of iterations that will slow down the calcs.  It will work with extra rows, but the more unneeded iteration will cause extra work.

Comment: Thank you. This works like a charm. I added `Indirect("Year"&CellWithYear)` also to make it dynamic.